# TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project using React and Firebase.
While doing that, I got this error:
`TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.auth is not a function`
React points this line for the error: `const auth = firebase.auth();`

My App.js file (I can't show all of it but the important part):

```
import './App.css';

import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';

firebase.initializeApp({
  // secret
})

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const analytics = firebase.analytics();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code after your imports is using the v8/compat style of calling Firebase. If you want to continue using that, you should import all Firebase SDKs you use from the `compat` path as shown in the documentation on [using the compat libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat).

So:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/analytics';

firebase.initializeApp({
  // secret
})

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const analytics = firebase.analytics();
```